# Sorting the output of my directory

Tags: bash, lubuntu, lxterminal

How can i create a new file called Option1.txt on my desktop. This file should 
 contain the contents of my 'home' directory. And how would i make my output is:

- Sorted alphabetically by entry extension.
- Includes any hidden files and folders.
- Shows all of the file sizes in human readable format

Answer (score 3):

`ls -alXh > Option1.txt`

`man ls` would help, also ... ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
ls -ahlX ~|awk '{printf "%-20s %-40s\n",$9,$5 }'>~/Desktop/Option1.txt
```

Sorted alphabetically by entry extension.(`Using ls -X`)

Includes any hidden files and folders.(Using `ls -a`)

Shows all of the file sizes in human readable format(Using `ls -lh`)

`awk '{print $9,$5 }` just prints the name and size of files and directories

and finally stores in Option.txt.

`%-20s %-40s\n` is for formatting the columns
**But** this will not print full directory name, as pointed out in the comments by @ Glenn Jackman ,if there are spaces in directory name.

So,

Another option would be ([source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70614/output-only-file-nameswith-spaces-in-ls-al?answertab=votes#tab-top))

```
ls -ahlX ~|gawk -F':[0-9]* ' '/:/{print $2}'>~/Desktop/Option1.txt
```

This one prints file names even if there are spaces.

But it is always a bad idea to parse ls.

Comment: > ~/Desktop/Option1.txt

Comment: @SylvainPineau My bad. Corrected it

Comment: `$9` won't contain the full filename if there are spaces.

Comment: @glennjackman yup you are right. Added a different way. Parsing `ls` is always a bad idea

Answer (score 0):

Parsing output of `ls` is never a good idea. My approach would be to use `du` to list disk usage for each file, with `--mad-depth` option to only list current directory (because `du` is recursive)  and then set `sort` command organize output based on the 2nd field.

```
 du --all --max-depth 1 --human-readable | sort --key=2
```

Redirecting that to a file then is simply `du --all --max-depth 1 --human-readable | sort --key=2 > outputFileName.txt`

You also may be interested in more verbose info than provided by `du`. Refer to my other answer that utilizes `find` and `du` ( although it may need to be modified to include `| sort` part ): [Command 'ls' showing directory size instead of block-size](https://askubuntu.com/q/723879/295286)